# How to make a clicked action operate only once

Tags: java, android, netbeans, dom-events

I just want an action to occur once, just once when clicked. Here is the code:

```
String previousValue = Counter.getText(" ");
Counter.setText("0");

AmouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  If(callquestion==1 && A.isFocusable()) {
        int d= Integer.parseInt(Counter.getText());
        int e= 10;
        int f=d+10;
        Counter.setText(f+" ");
    }
}
```

Note- Counter is a JLabel that displays the output, A is  Jlabel that holds the correct answer .I have A,B,C,D jlabels.
The initial value is 0. So I want each time a button is cliked, 10 just be added ones, if u click again. The 10 remains. I have callquestion1 to 20. So after a play gets the correct answer, he clicks the next to go to the next Qus.
I just need each button to add 10 if clicked again do nothing.

Comment: What is `Int`? Isn't it supposed to be `int`? Picky yes, but the Java compiler is even more picky, and so you don't want to post sort-of kind-of code, but rather only real code. Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Do you mean that you want them button be clicked just one time ?